# How to first edit in local Wordpress editor on page and the add code?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, localhost, local-installation, filesystem

I started a local WordPress site using DesktopServer. (Atom for coding). And I want to start creating the new website by first creating a "page" in local WordPress and creating a basic layout, and then to find the file and edit it in my code editor.

BUT I can't find the file of the new page I created (don't even know what it would be named) in the folder where my local Wordpress installation is. How can I find it? Or if it does not sync like that, how can I syncronize it?

Any answears would be much appreciated!

Comment: WordPress doesn't save HTML pages for you to edit. That's not how WordPress works. WordPress pages are saved in the database and they are displayed using PHP templates. The documentation for creating WordPress themes, which is where the templates are pulled from, is available here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/